# How to organize repository of common research papers for lab members?

Tags: software, reference-managers, lab-management

**The Problem**
I am a graduate student in a research lab with several other students, and as such we're all pursuing research and dissertation topics that are at least generally related in nature. We sometimes find papers relevant to others' topics during lit reviews, and right now we're just pushing them into a shared Google Drive folder.

That works fine, but the problem is that we don't really have a way to notify the relevant students when a paper is put into a specific folder (it's a fair-size lab with several students, and we're already drowning in noise emails ... we're not thrilled about adding more and basically CCing everyone the article touches).

**The Question**
We're looking for a service that essentially pushes a once-daily changelog of the filenames of added papers and the directories they've been committed to, sending them to the email addresses of all students in the lab (so that everyone can look over the daily list and skim it for anything interesting).

Does anyone know if such a thing exists? Or do you perhaps have an idea to help us out of our management woes?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use a collaborating tool like Trello? Every time you upload a new paper on your repository, you grab the link and add a post to the students' Trello project and all people (or the students you want) get notified by email.

Comment: Are you sure file update notifications are the way to go about this? In various institutes I am familiar with (and this includes institutes with more than 50 people), a regular internal colloquium where everyone takes turns at presenting their current research ensures that everyone has a rough idea of everyone else's research topics. Even if individual people do not get notified about individual publications like this, you usually know where to ask if you suspect previous publications on any topic to exist.

Comment: If you wish to stick with sharing files at the core, are you looking for an external or an internal solution? The reason I ask is that it strikes me as very unusual to rely on an external entity (Google in this case) as an intermediate node of communication within your own local lab, rather than using an own server for this purpose that you are guaranteed to control yourself (even if only the simplest form of file sharing is provided by making a sharing directory on one computer in the network accessible to everyone, without any form of version control, fine-grained access restrictions, etc.).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper hah! A few years ago, I'd have agreed, but now that all of my university's email resides on Microsoft's servers......

Comment: @SimonW: That strikes me as just as unusual (and would most probably be illegal at my place, but privacy laws differ from country to country).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper we do have something like a weekly lab meeting, but on most days different members add maybe half a dozen (total) papers that are relevant to them and may be useful to others; we found it tedious to wait until our weekly meeting to then recite all of the papers found and then identify which students to which it might pertain, so we were wondering about this "daily notification" idea. Also, we have "unlimited" Google Drive space--one of our students is at 45Gb and counting. I suppose we could create something like a NAS, but then we still have the notification problem.

Comment: @heliobacter: Ooh, seems I misunderstood your question as I thought you were only talking about papers you had created yourself (and found to possibly be relevant to others in your group). But even so, by all means, do not use the weekly meeting for reciting single papers; you could instead use it to present your currently focused research topics, so whoever is interested in something similar can ask you for any suggestions on related work. Concerning the storage space, I didn't see that as an issue.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper oh, so in light of that your comments make more sense ha. Perhaps I should have been more clear in my question. You're right, I'm talking about journal and conference papers we find performing lit reviews for papers we're writing and dissertation topics we're working on. We undoubtedly find those that are related to one or more people in the lab (certainly during systematic literature reviews), so as a courtesy we have been putting them into a shared directory sorted into subdirectories by topic. We're basically just crowdsourcing our searches to save everyone time. :)

Comment: How about version control tools like git/github? I believe it allows upload pdf files, and can notify project members about updates.

Comment: @Greg: If I am getting the OP right now, they want to store published papers by other people in there. As such, I think the individual files will rarely be updated, if at all (i.e. there is only ever one version of each file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this problem that I can think of is just to use **Mendeley** (or service with similar functionality) that allows people to form groups (public or private), based on their research interests. Then, all activity, such as adding relevant papers, etc., automatically appears on group members' news "wall", plus they can set up e-mail notifications and such. For more details, see corresponding Mendeley's pages: https://www.mendeley.com/features/collaborate and https://www.mendeley.com/groups.

Obviously, solutions for more complicated research workflows will require more specialized software tools: *open source*, *commercial off-the-shelf (COTS)* or *custom built*.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is connected with creating of the [Institutional_repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_repository).

> An institutional repository is an archive for collecting, preserving, and disseminating digital copies of the intellectual output of an institution, particularly a research institution.

[DSpace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSpace) is a software which helps you to organize an institutional repository.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should ask someone who knows how to use the Unix command line. It looks like it can be done in a fully automated way with a three-line script (`ls` with output redirected to a file + `diff` + `mail` + `cron`).

Answer (score 0):

*Papers* has functionality similar to this with "Papers Livfe", which allows you to create an online collection of papers with their attendant PDFs etc. and publish it online. You can restrict access to it to "Anyone" or invited people, so presumably you'd simply invite all the members of your lab.

Comment: Livfe? Does it have something to do with covfefe? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Another idea: create a yahoo group.  Make sure to allow attachments.  Each student in your group should subscribe to the yahoo group, with Daily Digest mode.  Each time you want to put an article in the shared repository, simply email it to the yahoo group, with a brief description in the body of the email.

I believe you can organize the attachments in a file structure.